# mysql database with web and android interface

Tags: android, mysql

My project needs to have mysql central database with android and website interface.

Could you guys please suggest me from where should i start n which language to select for development.

Comment: I don't get your question, what do you really want? cause if you want to have an android app, there is not 100 solutions, you must use android SDK

Comment: Yes, I must have to use android SDK, but question arise what will be website development language to choose n whats its structure like (1) web n mysql communicate directly and android n mysql directly irrespective of each other. (2) or I use a middle layer as xml such that both web n android will communicate xml, and xml communicate with mysql. With this update to xml will reflect in both..    I am new here so please guide me with project structure (which language n technolgy to use)...    Should I use only two layer(UI & db) or three layer(adding xml as middle layer)    Thank u

Answer (score 0):

it seems like , you will have a single database, all the CRUD operation to that database directly. then you have to **learn about REST api**.

here is a link, which is about creating REST API with php-slim, easy one to implement,

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

or google for REST API